# Convert java utf-8 string(one symbol) to ubuntu x11 Keysym

Tags: xorg, java, c++, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing an app that sends key presses from android's virtual keyboard to to some client. Currently I'm implementing the Ubuntu client, sending fake `x11` input events. I have a problem converting special UTF-8 characters or any non standard alphabet(testing using Cyrillic one) to x11 internal representation.
Function `XStringToKeysym` doesn't work at all. All it does correctly is converting latin characters.

I tried different encodings but none of them work completely.

Latest approach is this:

```
char *nativeString = ...; //utf-8 encoding
int k = 0;
unsigned long int code = 0;
char c;

while((c = nativeString[k++]) != '\0' ){
    code = code | ((c & 0xFF)  << (k-1)*8);
}
```

This adds some punctuation characters to the working list.
Same deal with Cyrillic alphabet though.

Any advice ?

**EDIT:**

On java side I get a string from socket:

```
String str = ...; // from socket
System.out.println(str); //prints out good
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
NativeCall.press(bytes,...);
```

On native side:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeCall_press(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array, jint modifiers) {

Window winFocus;
int    revert;
XGetInputFocus(display, &winFocus, &revert);


jboolean copy;
jbyte* bufferPtr = env->GetByteArrayElements(array, NULL);//got the bytes
jsize lengthOfArray = env->GetArrayLength(array);//length


for(int i = 0;i<lengthOfArray;i++){ //print the byte to make sure they are the same as in java code
    cout << (bufferPtr[i] & 0xff) << endl;
}


KeySym code = XStringToKeysym((const char *) bufferPtr);//doesn't work
cout << "Code: " << code << endl; //way #1

/*unsigned long int code = 0;   //way #2, works with some symbols

for(int i = 0;i<lengthOfArray;i++){
    char c = bufferPtr[i];
    code = code | ((c & 0xFF)  << i*8);
}*/


env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(array, bufferPtr, JNI_ABORT);

//send event, checked, works fine

XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, root_window, true, code, modifiers);
XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

XFlush(display);

event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, root_window, false, code, modifiers);
XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);


XFlush(display);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I'm not sure if the question belongs to AU but here goes... first: Are you sure you have UTF-8 chars. Java uses UTF-16 by default. As per this answer: [java utf8 encoding - char, string types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12187893/406423)

Comment: @MadMike Thank you ! Yes, I convert Java String to UTF-8 bytes

Comment: Could you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/876227/edit) your question and add how you do convert to UTF-8? I'd like to run you code but need to know what `...` on the first line `char *nativeString = ...;` means.

Comment: @MadMike Here you go

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit daft right now,  but I'm still missing the part what value you assign in the first line of  `char *nativeString = ...;`. What is the missing `...` part?

Comment: @MadMike `env->GetByteArrayElements(array, NULL)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't make head or tail of your code.

Comment: Can you rewrite the `char *nativeString = ...;`part so it has a fixed value which shows the problem?

Comment: @MadMike I think I got it know. I thought XStringToKeysym takes bytes as input but it takes ASCII strings like "up" or "f" . That is my mistake.